# protect a django rest api against sql injection

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, sql-injection

I have a REST API using django and i want to secure it against sql injection.

For example when i type on the browser : localhost:8080/MyApi/?id=3 or 'a'='a', i want to get an error.

I searched on the net and i find that sanitizing is a solution, but this solution can validate the fields of my api and not from the url

This is what i tried :

```
class FieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    Field = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_field(self, value):
       return bleach.clean(value)
```

How can i do that?

here is what i get :
[sql injection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reMWE.png)

Comment: To my knowledge, SQL injection is only ever really an issue in Django when you are writing raw queries using `RawSQL`.  You shouldn't have to worry about SQL injection in 99% of situations when you use Django.  What are you doing differently that requires you to be concerned about SQL injection?  (See the docs on SQL injection [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection))

Comment: Also sanitization is generally a really poor solution to SQL injection. The correct solution is *always* parameterized queries.

Comment: I am still new with django rest api, i have worked with an apache server before and i used a waf to secure it so normally if i tried to type a url like localhost:8080/MyApi/?id=3 or ‘a’=‘a’, i should get an error which i don’t get in my case with the rest api

Comment: The comments I see prior to writing this are correct, however if you want to be unnecessarily sure, you could always use logic to ensure the URL is valid, with a valid querystring. `id=3ora=a` is not a valid ID for anything so a quick call to `get_object_or_404()` will validate the worry you have for you...there is no way your initial query introduces SQL injection in your API. If you think it does, please show proof

Comment: i added an image of what i get

Comment: @rira _especially_ if you are new to django, you should not be questioning its SQL injection protection. It's an ORM and its primary concern is writing SQL on your behalf.. not trusting user input is a fundamental concern for django / other ORMs. You are free to use Apache WAF if you want on top of django as well... but people are telling you here it's not an issue. If you really want to do this yourself, it requires pretty solid django knowledge, but you would want to write a django middleware that intercepts all requests. It will live alongside other django security features.